# what's the difference between .js and .js.liquid in shopify?

Tags: shopify

In the assets section, there are files with `.js` and `.js.liquid` names.

What is the difference between the 2, which one should I use if I want to include a js file into a theme?

This is inside a .js.liquid file right now. I would like to construct a string made up of liquid variable. when I append this string inside a DOM element, it doesn't seem to show up.

```
var someString = '';
  {%for line in order.line_items%}
  someString += 'q='+{{line.quantity}}+'&p='+{{line.product.id}}+'&pp='+{{line.price}}+'&w='+{{line.grams}}+'&i='+{{line.product.featured_image|product_img_url|url_param_escape}}+'&n='+{{line.product.title|url_param_escape}}+'&';
  {%endfor%}

$('body').append(someString);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use liquid in `.js.liquid` files, but `.js` files are javascript only.

If you're including a regular js file, use the `.js` extension. If you've got liquid in the file as well, you'll need to use `.js.liquid`.

**EDIT:**

I don't think `order` can be accessed in a `.js.liquid` file. [See here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/order):

> The order object can be accessed in order email templates, the Thank You page of the checkout, as well as in apps such as Order Printer.

Also see [this discussion on the Shopify forums](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/using-liquid-in-javascript-trying-to-get-collection-title-in-jquery-callback-53043#comment-53047):

> You can only use Liquid filters and the global settings object in liquidified assets.
>
> It works like this: whenever you edit a .css.liquid of a .js.liquid file, or whenever you edit your theme settings, a new .css or .js file is created and then stored on our assets servers. Updating your shop in any other way will not update those files...
>
> Given the above, Shopify cannot expose store information (that is likely to change) in those files.

Comment: thanks. I am using liquid variables inside my `.js.liquid`, as shown above, but I am not getting `liquid` vars read correctly. the `liquid` objects are not showing up at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't add `.liquid` to the extension when you call the file with `| asset_url`. It might even cause a 404 error.

Steph is right that it will let you use liquid in your JS, just make sure to call the actual file without `.liquid`.

Comment: Good point @graygilmore. You would call `file.js.liquid` with `{{ "file.js" | asset_url | script_tag }}`.

Comment: @guest See my edit above about the liquid variables not showing up.

Comment: To put it succinctly: .js.liquid and .css.liquid files are STATIC, not DYNAMIC. The compiled js & css assets created from .js.liquid & .css.liquid files change only when the shop settings.json is changed, and thus do not have access to any shop, customer, or session information that is dynamic. Dynamic javascript must live in a script tag in a snippet or theme file.