# Can I use liquid inside JS file?

Tags: javascript, liquid

I'm using Shopify and I need to show some message if specific product tag is exist. I need to check for product tags from JS file and need to know how can I do that.

I tried to use {{product.tags}} in the js file but I got an error, I also tried that in .js.liquid file and it still throw an error.

```
{% assign clearance = false %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
            {% if tag contains 'Clearance' %}
                 {% assign clearance = true %}
            {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

There is a way that I could use that in js? If not, how can I grab all product tags in js way? I know I can do that from liquid file but I have to do that only in the js file.

Comment: I hope this will help you out [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983518/whats-the-difference-between-js-and-js-liquid-in-shopify)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for an extension to Javascript called [`jsx`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Aside from that, natively, you have [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you can only use expressions in that, no looping or other logic (aside from [ternary expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)).

If what you are looking for is not related to creating HTML, but only to modifying a variable (or executing other code on data), you can use standard Javascript:

```
let clearance = false;
for (const tag in product.tags) { // this assumes product.tags is an object
for (const tag of product.tags) { // this assumes product.tags is an array
    if (tag.includes('Clearance') {
        clearance = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can access product.tags from js file?

Answer (score 0):

The .js.liquid file will only accept translation string as var in Liquid (example: {{ "my_text" | t }}.

If you want to use other kind of Liquid strings in Javascript code, you may use a section and include your javascript inside {% javascript %} tags.

This will also work in a snippet or a template.